# How do I add an image from a list in python using docx?

Tags: python, image, ms-word, jupyter-notebook, docx

I wrote a code that takes a screenshot that I want to paste into a word document using docx. So far I have to save the image as a png file. The relevant part of my code is:

```
from docx import Document
import pyautogui
import docx

doc = Document()

images = []

img = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (some region))

images.append(img)
img.save(imagepath.png)

run =doc.add_picture(imagepath.png)
run
```

I would like to be able to add the image without saving it. Is it possible to do this using docx?

Comment: Are you using `python-docx` package? Also, if you don't want to save as a file, are you able to take the screenshot and save to a `variable`? What is the format of that image then?

Comment: Yes, I use python-docx and the screenshoots I take are saved in a list. The code I'm actually using is quite extense, but I'll edit my post to show how the relevant part works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to [add_picture — Document objects — python-docx 0.8.10 documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html?highlight=add_picture#docx.document.Document.add_picture), `add_picture` can import data from a stream as well.

As per [Screenshot Functions — PyAutoGUI 1.0.0 documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function), `screenshot()` produces a PIL/Pillow image object which [can be `save()`'d with a `BytesIO()` as destination to produce a compressed image data stream in memory](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes).

So that'll be:

```
import io
imdata = io.BytesIO()

img.save(imdata, format='png')
imdata.seek(0)

doc.add_picture(imdata)
del imdata    # cannot reuse it for other pictures, you need a clean buffer each time
              # can use .truncate(0) then .seek(0) instead but this is probably easier
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! I'm trying to understand what 'imdata.seek(0)' does.

Comment: @JoséChamorro https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=seek#methods-of-file-objects